# Solution to draw objects on layers and share maps

Tags: leaflet, style, circle, leaflet-draw

I'm looking for an online solution to build custom maps on top of OSM/Bing/Google layers and share them via export or link. I need to find an address, draw and drop lines, polygons, circles, add and remove markers. I'd like to change color and opacity of those objects.

I tried :

- Leaflet with Leaflet.draw, Leaflet.StyleEditor and Leaflet.print | it works but it shows limits when printing big maps to PDF (even the controls and boxes are printed) plus I can't save it to edit later.
- share.mapbbcode.org and it's really good except I can't draw circle, see [my contact with the author](https://github.com/MapBBCode/share.mapbbcode.org/issues/38)
- Ilya Zverev (the author of mapbbcode.org) points me to [umap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/) which is great but have the same limitation with circles

I'm disappointed as I see it's close to fits my needs but I don't know how to make it. 
Has someone else been successful at drawing lines, polygons, circles (and changing the color and opacity) and saving/sharing maps ?

Comment: I suspect your question is a bit too broad to get meaningful answers. For example, it is entirely possible to save and edit shapes with leaflet draw, but not, generally speaking, without posting to a server for later retrieval. In short, none of these solutions are likely to provide the application you are looking for without a fair amount of work and custom javascript. If you post specific problems you have encountered, with details of what you've tried, you are more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Hi @toms, I configured a LAMP to use mapbbcode and storing/sharing/editing maps works pretty well but circles not. 2 solutions : make circles possible to compute and store or adding the capacity to put circle markers as I only need 4 types (50m/100m/150m/250m)